# использовать css только для одного представления

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как использовать *css только для одного представления*? В частности,Есть следующий код:

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                          "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

И нужно *только для одного* отдельного представления сделать фон всего "body".

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте указать в `application.html.erb` условие:

```
<% content_for :specific_view do %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "specific_view_css" %>
<% end %>
```

Здесь `specific_view` представление для которого нужен отдельный CSS, а `specific_view_css` имя файла без расширения в `/assets`. [Прочитать подробнее](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag).

Comment: Появилась следующая проблема: появляется ошибка: "Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( мой файл.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server".
Сделав это я получаю этот файл подключенный ко всем представлениям...

Comment: @ВалерийТутаев скорее всего, у вас в `application.css` (или `.scss`) есть `require_tree`, которое "затягивает всё". Поправьте там директивы и включите только то, что надо. В остальном вы всё сделали правильно.